# Is there any way to die in "The Plan"?

Tags: the-plan

Of course there is the dramatic ending.  But is there any other way to die?

--EDIT--
After playing through the game again, and trying to die to both the leaf and the spider, it seems neither actually causes death... Question has been rephrased.

Comment: Is it possible to go downwards at all in the game?

Comment: I don't believe so.  You can slow your ascent, but to my knowledge you can't reverse it.